# Knot diagram coloured with only one colour by any colouring

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $K$ be a knot diagram of a knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose $K$ admits only trivial colourings by any quandle (a colouring is said to be trivial if only one colour is used to colour the diagram). Then is it true that $K$ is trivial; i.e. Unknotted

Comment: What is a quandle? And what kind of diagram is used for the knot? Is it obtained by laying the knot down on a plane and sketching? [If so how can one "color" this with one color anyway, in the sense of not making adjacent colors the same?]

Comment: @coffeemath: The demand is that at a crossing (so that there appear to be three strands of the knot) all three strands are colored differently *or* all the same.

Comment: Still don't know what a quandle is (was that a typo for some other known term, I haven't heard of quandle...) Also do you really mean all three the same is OK in a coloring?

Comment: Yes, to account for Reidemeister moves. If your knot is $k$-colorable, you want it to be $k$-colorable even after a Reidemeister move (so that $k$-colorability is a knot invariant). For instance, start with the unknot; obviously 1-colorable; now do a Type I to get something that's obviously not 1-colorable unless you allow all three at a crossing to be the same colored. A quandle is some type of algebraic gadget that some knot theorists like; I know nothing about them.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental quandle is a complete knot invariant.  What this means, is that every nontrivial knot has a nontrivial coloring by its fundamental quandle.

So, to answer your question, yes.  If a knot has only trivial colorings for every quandle, then it must be the trivial knot.

See [Scott Carter's paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.4429.pdf) for more details.

Comment: I thought the fundamental quandle of a knot is a complete invariant up to reflection (David Joyce82)?

Comment: You may be right. I am not very up on quandles. But I will say that I often only care about knots up to reflection.